# PHP 5.4 can't include file with permissions 777

Tags: linux, permissions, php5

I'm working on setting up PHP 5.4, and I've set a library up in `/usr/share/php/`
I've set `include_path='.:/usr/share/php'`, and was not able to include anything with a relative require_once.

I've set the include up to the explicit path, and get a permission error, even after `chmod`ing the file to `777`.

```
failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT

Here are the permissions for the file I'm trying to include:

```
/usr/share/php
drwxrwxrwx. 64 1001 1001 4096 Sep 29  2011 Zend

/usr/share/php/Zend/
-rwsrwsrwt.  1 1001 1001  12959 Mar  1  2011 Config.php
```

And the two require lines I tried:

```
require_once('/usr/share/php/Zend/Config.php');
require_once('Zend/Config.php');
```

Comment: What distribution?  SELinux/AppArmor?

Comment: @Kyle Smith CentOS 6.0. No AppArmor or SELinux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you have execution permission on the folder your lib is sitting in 
you need to enable apache(or whatever web server you are using) with execution permission on the folder containing the files you want to include/require

Comment: Chmodded the folder as well, and still get the same error.

Comment: could you paste the output of ls -la command that shows permissions on the lib you want to include and the folder containing it
and also the lines of php code you are using for the require once ?